# Showing progress in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wanting to show the progress in a winforms app, and have it write to the application. [image]

Above shows where I would like to do this. I have all my methods in their own class, and I have written a method with the following code:

```
public List<string> WriteToProgress(string str)
        {
            List<string> progress = new List<string>();
            progress.Add(str);
            return progress;
        }
```

My question is, how can I get my progress list to show in the listbox in my application?

Comment: That's an odd function.  How are you using it?

Comment: A more accurate name for the function you posted would be `PutThisStringInAnEmptyListAndReturnTheList()` You are not storing the string, adding it to somewhere else, or doing _anything_ with it other than returning it inside a list.

Comment: To be clear, I am facing a problem I am not 100% sure how to tackle, so my first thought was to add the strings to a list, and then wondered if I could replicate that list in the listbox in real time, somehow. Based off of the reactions though, it would appear that is a foolish plan...

Comment: You hinted at something about methods in each class.  I'm guessing your best design would probably have each class raise an event and have your form listen for that event, then update your ListBox in that event.

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, are looking for something like this:

```
using System.Linq;
...

// Add step to progress, return list of steps
public List<string> WriteToProgress(string step) {
  // Add step (if it's not null or empty) to progress
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(step))
    myListBox.Items.Add(step);

  // collect and return all steps as a list:
  return myListBox.Items
    .OfType<Object>()
    .Where(o => o != null)
    .Select(o => o.ToString())
    .ToList();
} 

...

WriteToProgress("step #1: db connect"); 
WriteToProgress("step #2: uploading"); 
...
// Let's report the progress so far
var progress = WriteToProgress("step #N: reporting");

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, progress));
```